# clamscan /boot/System.map-5.0.0-32-generic: Access denied

Tags: boot, permissions, clamav

I just installed and updated clamav. I am now running clamscan from the terminal for the boot directory. I keep receiving Access Denied errors for files within the boot directory. I'd like to scan my entire computer. Is this possible with clamav? Is it normal to have Access Denied Errors? Are there any work arounds? If so, are there any potential negative effects that could be caused by the work arounds that you can foresee?

```
ben@ben-Lenovo-G50-45:/boot$ clamscan
/boot/System.map-5.0.0-32-generic: Access denied
/boot/System.map-4.15.0-118-generic: Access denied
/boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-32-generic: Access denied
/boot/memtest86+.elf: OK
/boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-45-generic: OK
/boot/memtest86+_multiboot.bin: OK
/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-45-generic: Access denied
/boot/System.map-5.4.0-48-generic: Access denied
/boot/config-5.4.0-48-generic: OK
/boot/config-4.15.0-118-generic: OK
/boot/memtest86+.bin: OK
/boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-48-generic: OK
/boot/config-5.4.0-45-generic: OK
/boot/config-4.15.0-54-generic: OK
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-118-generic: OK
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-54-generic: OK
/boot/config-5.0.0-32-generic: OK
/boot/System.map-4.15.0-54-generic: Access denied
/boot/System.map-5.4.0-45-generic: Access denied
/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-48-generic: Access denied
/boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-32-generic: OK
/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-54-generic: OK
/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-118-generic: Access denied

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 8920319
Engine version: 0.102.4
Scanned directories: 1
Scanned files: 14
Infected files: 0
Total errors: 9
Data scanned: 11.18 MB
Data read: 376.11 MB (ratio 0.03:1)
Time: 53.269 sec (0 m 53 s)
ben@ben-Lenovo-G50-45:/boot$
```

Comment: Doesn't clamscan needs root-rights to do it's work .. `sudo clamscan` should do it.Still it is pretty much unnecessary to do virus-scan on Linux IMHO.

Comment: That worked! Lol. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help. I have added it as an answer. Please accept that answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clamscan needs root-rights )elevated privileges) to scan all files.

Plwase use `sudo clamscan` to achieve that.